# Поиск расстояния до локального максимума в столбце

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Имеется колонка 'A' с числовыми значениями. Размер тысяча строк.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.randint(100, size=1000)})
```

С помощью метода `Series.rolling()` ищем максимум в скользящем окне из 50 значений колонки 'A' и записываем этот максимум в новую колонку 'B':

```
df['B'] = df['A'].rolling(50).max()
```

Требуется найти расстояние (в строках) между текущей строкой и строкой, в которой находится максимум, и записать это значение в новую колонку 'C'. В данном примере расстояние может принимать значение от 0 (максимум в скользящем окне находится на текущей строке) до 49 (максимум находится в самом начале скользящего окна).

---

Пример кода, который не работает:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(Example.csv)
(df.assign(dist=df['C'].rolling(50, min_periods=1)
    .apply(lambda x: x.idxmax(), raw=False)
    .astype('int8'))
    .eval("dist = abs(dist - index)", inplace = True)
    .astype('int8'))
```

Файл Example.csv  лежит по ссылке:
[https://ru.files.fm/u/vuknckfv][1]

Выдается ошибка:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'astype'

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
In [212]: window = 50

In [213]: (df.assign(dist=df['A'].rolling(window, min_periods=1)
     ...:                        .apply(lambda x: x.idxmax(), raw=False)
     ...:                        .astype('int8'))
     ...:    .eval("dist = abs(dist - index)")
     ...:    .astype('int8'))
     ...:
Out[213]:
      A  dist
0    72     0
1    37     1
2    87     0
3    87     1
4    58     2
5    51     3
6    47     4
7    64     5
8    57     6
9    29     7
..   ..   ...
990  27    24
991  21    25
992  19    26
993  36    27
994  26    28
995  95    29
996  24    30
997  97    31
998  81    32
999  68    33

[1000 rows x 2 columns]
```

PS если в первых 50 строках (размер плавающего окна) расстояние должно быть `NaN` (не определено), то уберите аргумент `min_periods=1`

Comment: У меня не появляется столбец "dist". :(

Comment: Для того чтобы он появился надо присвоить результат обратно ‘df’ или использовать аргумент “inplace=True“ в вызове “.eval()”

Comment: 985
93
97.0
1047.0
986
69
97.0
1048.0
987
77
97.0
1049.0
988
9
97.0
1050.0
989
37
97.0
1051.0
990
25
97.0
1052.0
991
11
97.0
1053.0
992
50
93.0
1031.0
993
48
93.0
1032.0
994
99
99.0
1024.0
995
61
99.0
1025.0
996
18
99.0
1026.0
997
72
99.0
1027.0
998
58
99.0
1028.0
999
54
99.0
1029.0

Comment: Без параметра min_period=1 не запускается. Также не хочет работать с последней строчкой .astype('int8'). И результаты неправдоподобные получаются. Последние 30 строчек в колонке 'dist' значения в диапазоне 1030-1050, хотя всего имеется 1000 строчек.

Comment: В Jupyter notebook код работает нормально. В Visual Studio Code такой же результат не получается. :(

Comment: @Maksim_19, я с `Visual Studio Code` не работал... Но если это работает в `Jupyter notebook`, то ответ на данный вопрос вы получили (как мне кажется) ;-)

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ. Хотя использовать этот метод у меня не получается. Слишком он "капризный". На простых данных работает, беру таблицу побольше - отказывается. В таблице только данные типа int64, float64. Пустых ячеек нет, но всякий случай использую метод df.fillna(0). Однако Ваш код ругается: "ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer." Промучился с бубном пару часов, но заставить его работать не смог.   :((

Comment: @Maksim_19, попробуйте привести в вопросе __воспроизводимый__ пример данных (чтобы воспроизводилась ошибка)

Comment: Добавил в вопросе пример, который дает ошибку